# First day Of this week and last week

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am currently getting first day Of this week and last week values with vbscript function in 2/12/2009 format. I was wondering if it was possible with SQL query.

Comment: What do you regard as the first day of the week?  Some say Sunday, others say Monday (and others may say something else).  And not every application on your SQL Server my have the same answer, so you might want to check it with SELECT @@DATEFIRST and/or use SET DATEFIRST to change it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

These statements should do what you want in TSQL. Note, the statements are based on the current date. You can replace getdate() for whatever date you wish:

```
Select dateadd(wk, datediff(wk, 0, getdate()) - 1, 0) as LastWeekStart
Select dateadd(wk, datediff(wk, 0, getdate()), 0) as ThisWeekStart
Select dateadd(wk, datediff(wk, 0, getdate()) + 1, 0) as NextWeekStart
```

There are lots of other [date routines here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114592/getdate-last-month/1114784#1114784).

Comment: Nice Answer, Ben.  Readers should note though that this will return the first day of these weeks as defined by SET DATEFIRST (and as seen with SELECT @@DATEFIRST), which may or may not be the same as what the reader expects.

Comment: @RBarry Young - Very good point. Thanks for calling this out.

Comment: As George noted below, if the datepart value of your date is the same as your DateFirst value, the answer is wrong. Ben's answer works, only if today's datepart was equal to the DateFirst value. Another example using last Sunday's date:
SET DATEFIRST 1
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, '11/29/2015'), '11/29/2015') AS CorrectThisWeekStart,
  DATENAME(WEEKDAY, '11/29/2015')

SET DATEFIRST 7
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, '11/29/2015'), '11/29/2015') AS CorrectThisWeekStart,
  DATENAME(WEEKDAY, '11/29/2015')

Comment: The answer of George works better for the case of first day of current week

Answer (score 4):

Ben's answer gives the wrong answer if today is Sunday.  Regardless of whether the first day of the week is Sunday or Monday, the current date should be included in the current week.  When I run his code for 3/24/2013, it gives me a ThisWeekStart of 3/25/2013.  I used the following code instead:
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1 - DATEPART(DW, '3/24/2013'), '3/24/2013')

Comment: Add this as a comment to his answer, or include a full answer as opposed to an extension to an additional answer.  Your answer should stand in isolation; as is, I have to look at "Ben's answer" to know what you're talking about.

Answer (score 0):

Get the first day of current week.
for extra information use this link.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofweek

```
select date(curdate()-DAYOFWEEK(curdate()-1)) as dat;
```