# SQL Get date of first day of previous week

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, date

I would like get a date of first day of the previous week from a date.
So I have this:

```
select "start_of_week" = dateadd(week, datediff(week, 0, getdate()), 0);
```

This code show the data of the first day of week but not the first day of previous week.

How can I modify it?

Comment: `dateadd(week, datediff(week, 0, getdate()), -1)`

Comment: @artm That will give the previous day. Just try it.

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu You're right.

Comment: possible duplicate of [First day Of this week and last week](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1150251/first-day-of-this-week-and-last-week)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work for you, just substract one more week from the date that you already generate with your code:

`select 
   "start_of_week" = dateadd(week, -1 , dateadd(week, datediff(week, 0, getdate()), 0))`