# SQL - Only select records from weekends

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I need to write a SQL Select statement to select all the records where DateCreated falls on a weekend for the last 4 weeks.  I know I can do this by hard-coding the select like the one below.  But I was wondering if there was an easier way using T-sql date functions.

```
SELECT * FROM audit_table 
WHERE DateCreated BETWEEN '07-31-2010 00:00:00' AND '08-01-2010 23:59:59'
  OR DateCreated BETWEEN '07-24-2010 00:00:00' AND '07-25-2010 23:59:59'
  OR DateCreated BETWEEN '07-17-2010 00:00:00' AND '07-18-2010 23:59:59'
  OR DateCreated BETWEEN '07-10-2010 00:00:00' AND '07-11-2010 23:59:59'
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

try this

```
where DateCreated  >= DATEADD(DD, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, DATEADD(WK,-4,GETDATE()))+0, 0)
and datepart(dw,DateCreated) in (1,7) -- Sat and Sun only
```

[Edit] see comment about datefirst[/Edit]

Comment: Note that you need to beware of what your SQL Server installation thinks is the first day of the week - see the documentation for `@@DATEFIRST` - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187766.aspx

Comment: `DateCreated  >= cast(floor(cast(DATEADD(WK,-4,GETDATE()) as float)) as datetime)` :)

Comment: And on sql 2008 you can do CONVERT(DATE,DATEADD(WK,-4,GETDATE()))

Comment: Dang, I can't wait to upgrade to 2008!

Answer (score 3):

Check out the second answer on [GETDATE last month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114592/getdate-last-month/1114740#1114740).  It has a pretty robust rundown of different ways to get dates out of SQL.

Specifically he lists "dateadd(ms, -3, dateadd(wk, datediff(wk, 0, getdate()) + 1, 0))" as a way to get this weekend.  This can easily be translated to get the weekends that you need.

Answer (score 0):

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/07/23/sql-server-udf-get-the-day-of-the-week-function/