# SQL Server get records before a defined time

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am trying to get a list of records that have been in the system only before 05:00:00 pm of the day the query is being run. I have this query that works in the basic testing, but I wanted to see if there is a better option than to do the SQL concatenation.

```
select *
  from Payment
 where createTimestamp <= CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), Getdate(), 120) +' '+'17:00:00';
```

This query will be used on SQL Server 2008.

Comment: before 5pm of that day... do you also only want records SINCE 5 pm the previous day?

Comment: Does "only before 5 PM of the day the query is run" mean "any before 5 PM of the given day" (including items many days before) or does it mean "on the current day but before 5 PM"?

Comment: @Neil: This is for a scheduled job which runs every Wednesday. So we just take all the payments that are in "To Be Paid" status. So there is no requirement to look for previous day time. I have to just look for the "To Be Paid" status. 
@Thomas: The former.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Select ...
From Payment
Where CreateTimeStamp <= DateAdd(hh, 17, DateDiff(d, 0, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP))
```

Another option given that you are using SQL Server 2008

```
Select ...
From Payment
Where CreateTimeStamp <= DateAdd(hh, 17, Cast(Cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP As Date) As DateTime))
```

Answer (score 0):

This will retrieve all records with a `createTimestamp` between 12am and 5pm today.

```
select *
  from Payment
 where createTimestamp
       between dateadd(dd, datediff(dd, 0, getdate()), 0)
           and dateadd(hh, 17, dateadd(dd, datediff(dd, 0, getdate()), 0))
```

This will retrieve all records with a `createTimestamp` between 5pm yesterday and 5pm today.

```
select *
  from Payment
 where createTimestamp
       between dateadd(hh, -7, dateadd(dd, datediff(dd, 0, getdate()), 0))
           and dateadd(hh, 17, dateadd(dd, datediff(dd, 0, getdate()), 0))
```

For more fun with sql dates check out my answer to [GETDATE last month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114592/getdate-last-month/1114740#1114740).