# How to find the date of the first day of the current week

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

How to find the date of the first day of the current week in transact-sql(t-sql)?. What T-SQL statement do we need to use for this?.

This is always be a Sunday. For example if we run the sql statement on today(2015-02-18) or any day of the current week it should give the result 2015-02-15 which is a Sunday.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: `SELECT Cast(Dateadd(DAY, 1 - Datepart(WEEKDAY, Getdate()), Getdate()) AS DATE) `

Answer (score 3):

One of possible way to get the date on Sunday for the current week.

```
SELECT  DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 0, GETDATE()), -1) AS SundayOfCurrentWeek
```

Answer (score 2):

**Using DATEPART**

It depends on the settings of the server, but if it is configured to think that weeks start on Sundays, then this would work:

```
SELECT CAST(DATEADD(day, 1-DATEPART(weekday, GETDATE()), GETDATE()) AS date)
```

[DATEPART](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ms174420.aspx) with `weekday` parameter gives the day of the week. Then this number is subtracted from the current date and converted to `date` to remove the time part.

> When datepart is week (wk, ww) or weekday (dw), the return value
>   depends on the value that is set by using [SET DATEFIRST](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ms181598.aspx).
>
> To see the current setting of SET DATEFIRST, use the @@DATEFIRST
>   function. The setting of SET DATEFIRST is set at execute or run time
>   and not at parse time.

So to play it safe make sure that DATEFIRST is set to 7 (default, U.S. English), which means Sunday.

**Using DATEDIFF**

Another variant uses [DATEDIFF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx):

```
SELECT DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, '20150104', GETDATE()), '20150104')
```

It would always return Sunday. Magic date `20150104` can be any date that is Sunday.

> Specifying SET DATEFIRST has no effect on DATEDIFF. DATEDIFF always
>   uses Sunday as the first day of the week to ensure the function is
>   deterministic.

On the one hand it is good, because it is guaranteed to return Sunday, even if you forget to set DATEFIRST. But, on the other hand it is not flexible and doesn't suit those who consider, say, Monday to be the first day of the week (those that are not in US).

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
Select dateadd(wk, datediff(wk, 0, getdate()) - 1, 0) as LastWeekStart
Select dateadd(wk, datediff(wk, 0, getdate()), 0) as ThisWeekStart
Select dateadd(wk, datediff(wk, 0, getdate()) + 1, 0) as NextWeekStart
```

for more information

[GETDATE last month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114592/getdate-last-month/1114784#1114784)

Comment: your querys will find mondays, not sundays

Comment: @t-clausen.dk in some countries the first day of the week is not Sunday)